# Why doesn't this javascript work?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use the pushstate but it doesn't work:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>function myFunction() {
alert("lel"); 
var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
window.history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");
} 
</script>
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()"></body>
</html>
```

The alert comes up so I know the function is being executed, but nothing happens to the browser's address bar. Why?

EDIT: I tested this using Firefox, Chrome and IE. The script only works on IE and not on firefox or chrome.

Comment: It is working for me. What browser are you testing in?

Comment: `pushstate` isn't widely supported. IE10 supports it as does FF and chrome, but nothing below IE 10.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using firefox 23.0.1

Comment: You can see the browser support for `pushState` at the very end of the page where you copy / pasted the example from : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: How are you requesting the page? From an HTTP server? Directly from disk? If you're using `file://`, push state probably just isn't allowed -- `SecurityError: The operation is insecure.`

Comment: I'm requesting the page directly from disk. That's probably why then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to request the page from an HTTP server not directly from disk otherwise it wouldn't work. Thanks Jonathan.